# ASP.NET WebAPI Caching

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement caching on a WebAPI service. The goal is to store user data in a cached object bound to a token that should be passed with each request, instead of sending the user data with each request (the UI layer is running independently of the WebAPI layer in their own app pools). I can't seem to find an implementation that works. I have a static helper class `TokenHandler` that is called by the controller to deal with the token. My code to insert the object is:

```
        public static string insertToken(AccessToken token)
        {
            Cache cache = new Cache();
            string key = string.Empty;
            do
            {
                key = generateTokenKey();
            } while (cache.Get(key) != null);
            token.KeyValue = key;
            cache.Insert(key, token, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20));
            return key;
        }
```

I know from the get-go that this is not correct, because we are not supposed to use the `Cache()` constructor, per [the MSDN entry on Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.cache.aspx) but I cannot find anything else that will actually compile. The only other solutions I have found dealt with `Page.Cache`, which I am not caching from a page. I am trying to avoid a database call, if possible. I know its probably something stupid-simple that I am missing.

Comment: No, it just generates a random character string, it does not interact with the cache at all.

Comment: In addition: Use dependency injection to actually access the HttpContext as described in the answer I linked.

Comment: I had tried `Cache cache = HttpContext.Current.Cache;` from another question at first, but it did not want to build. I tried it again, and it worked. Very odd... I knew it was something stupid simple.